# Set size for a partial view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm  wasn't quite sure what tags to add for this questions so if this doesn't belong to some of the tags, I apologise.

I have four partial views in one page and when I add data to them they keep expanding. How  do I set the size of a partial view?

What I want is to make those 4 look as 4 solid (non expanding)  windows and have scrolls so when users add more things, they can scroll down in each individual view. Please see the following pictures
[image]

[image]
Thanks!
Cheers!

Comment: please post what you have tried, coding and pictures are appreciated

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried anything because I have no clue. Im absolutely hopeless in this matter. I don't even know whether it should be handled from back or front.

Comment: well, make an illustration of what you would like for starters

Comment: Please see the added pictures. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably achieve the desired result through the use of overflow-y:auto.

Each partial view would be wrapped in a wrapper:

```
<div class="partialViewWrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_YourPartialView")
</div>
```

The wrapper would be styled as:

```
.partialViewWrapper
{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

This should provide scrollbars when vertical content exceeds the height of the wrapper div. If you want the wrapper to always have a scrollbar, you would use overflow-y:scroll

Comment: will be enought only `overflow-y:auto`

Comment: You are correct, aleha. I edited my answer to reflect that option.